# How to prefetch a Next.JS dynamic route?

Tags: typescript, next.js, app-router

In Next.JS AppRouter we have `router.prefetch(href: string)` how can we prefetch a dynamic route?

I would like to prefetch all chunked assets (js and css) not the page with actual data

Let say we have `app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx` how to call `router.prefetch`?